# Exported MySQL tables have wrong datetimes

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In PhpMyAdmin, I executed a SELECT query, and then clicked the Export button at the bottom of the page. On the page that loaded next, I clicked the Go button, which downloaded an sql file to my computer. When I open that file up, and compare the data in it with the data in my database, all of the datetimes in the file are 6 hours later than those in the database. I can't figure out why the data is different.

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue. Are you 6 hours different from GMT?

Comment: I am, yes. Is exported data always converted to GMT time?

Comment: Yes, by default. See the linked question for how to change this setting.